# jQueryUI Modal dialog not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've got a simple task that's driving me nuts.

My jQuery code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialog_open").button().click(function () {
             $("#dialog_frame").open();
        });
        });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dialog_frame').dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        height:500,
        width:500,
        modal:true;
        });
    });
```

HTML for the button:

```
                    <td>
                    <input type="button" id="dialog_open" value="Open" />
                </td>
```

HTML for the content of the modal popup:

```
<div id="dialog_frame" style="display:none;">
    <p>I am here!</p>    
</div>
```

When I clock on my button, nothing happens. I also see the content for the dialog doesn't hide unless I put the display:none; in there.

What am I doing wrong? I've included links to jQuery, jQueryUI, and the jQueryUI CSS files but can't get this to work! (I've got other sites that work fine)

Comment: What is supposed to do: `$("#dialog_open").button().click(...)` ???

Comment: i think he might be using 3rd party css to customize button.. like bootstrap.css

Comment: Don't you have a syntax error in `modal:true;` ??

Comment: I thought it should open my dialog...I based that on the documentation on the jQueryUI site.

Comment: Have you check your console? Isn't .button() returning error too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `open` method of the `.dialog` widget should be invoked using :

```
$("#dialog_frame").dialog('open');
```

(instead of `$("#dialog_frame").open()` - doesn't this line of code raise an error in your javascript console ?)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#dialog_open").button().click(function () {
       $('#dialog_frame').dialog({
           height:500,
           width:500,
           modal:true
       });
    });
});
```